# json/java write at next free line

Tags: java, json

I try to write a json file and I want to get an output like this:

```
{"key1" : "value"..}
{"key4" : "value"..}
```

in the same file. 
I've done it this way:

```
public class Writer {   
    public void writerMeth(String[] dataArray) throws IOException{

    JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();         
    builder.add("key1",dataArray[0])
            .add("key2",dataArray[1])
            .add("key3",dataArray[2]) ; 
        JsonStructure output=builder.build();   
        HashMap<String, Object> config =  new HashMap<String, Object>();
        config.put(JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING, true);
        JsonWriterFactory factory =Json.createWriterFactory(config);
        JsonWriter writer = factory.createWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.json"));        
        writer.write(output);               
        writer.close();
```

My problem is that by calling the method the old data is deleted; I want to write the next entry at the next free line. It is possible?

Comment: Read the file.json first store it in a variable and add new and rewrite onto the file

Comment: You could say `new FileOutputStream("file.json", true)` which would append to the file instead of rewriting it

Comment: Ah sorry I see the old data .   I  write 10 entries in a while loop and then I would like to rewrite the file . how can I do this?